# kobold2d ios device build failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

i am trying to run my kobold2d project on my iphone 4 but it gives me build failed ,

Apple Mach-O linker error.

Cocos2d projects run fine so i don't have any problem with my provisioning profile.I am opening kobold2-0-4.xworkspace. By the way the same project runs perfecty on ios Simulator

Error is:File not found: /Users/bigayvaz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-canokjowlgyrikflbvkipwwnizsr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libkobold2d-ios.a

Linker command failed with exit code 1

By the way i use xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Please post the complete linker error. Not everyone here has a crystal ball, so posting the complete error will make it more likely that you will get help.

Comment: I edited it now sorry about that